# How to configure Systemd service unit to start Node app with "npm start" instead of "app.js"

Tags: linux, systemd, node.js, npm

**Environment:** CentOS 8, Node.js, Digital Ocean Droplet

My Systemd setup starts a node app with the following command.  It works as expected.

```
$ sudo systemctl start myapp
```

File 1: `/etc/systemd/system/myapp.service`

```
[Unit]
Description = My App 
After = network.target

[Service]
ExecStart = /root/start-myapp.sh
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

File 2: `/root/start-myapp.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/node /srv/myapp/app.js
```

However when I'm not using Systemd I normally start my app with Node Package Manager using the command, `npm start`.  I'd rather have the Systemd unit also start the app with `npm start`.

Unfortunately it threw an error when I changed `app.js` to `npm start` in `/root/start-myapp.sh`,

```
/usr/bin/node /srv/myapp/npm start
```

I made another attempt by switching the path from `node` to `npm` but it produced the same error.

```
/usr/bin/npm /srv/myapp/npm start
```

**Question:** How do I get my Systemd unit file to start my app with the command `npm start`?

Answer (score 9):

I'm running a similar setup on Debian, and my service looks like this:

```
...

[Service]
Environment=NODE_PORT=3000
Type=simple
User=www-data
Restart=on-failure
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/<your-code-directory>
ExecStart=npm start

...
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

I didn't have luck with filipe's answer but I found [this one](https://techoverflow.net/2020/12/29/systemd-unit-for-autostarting-nodejs-application-npm-start/) that is very close!

```
[Unit]
Description=My application

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
User=nobody
Group=nobody
WorkingDirectory=/opt/myapplication
ExecStart=/usr/bin/npm start

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

A major difference being the `ExecStart` has `/usr/bin/` preceeding the `npm start`.
The other is that it excludes the environment, I added a port flag to mine so `npm start --Port 5000`

I also found [this](https://www.terlici.com/2015/04/20/hosting-deploying-nodejs-centos.html) to be a useful article pertaining to setting up services if you're extremely new to it like myself.

It doesn't cover the question but does have some other useful tips.

I was also on Centos 7

Answer (score 0):

if you manually exec npm start and you check ps -ef | node
you will find what actually executing, that is node. Node is the only executable that runs everything. I'll give you an example:

```
/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v18.16.0/bin/node /home/ubuntu/aiphotoviewer/node_modules/.bin/next start
```

Your node will be in another location but same concept. Just npm run, ps -ef | node to check the actual running process and copy it and you're good to go

Hope it help.

P.S. maybe i'm too late? it's been 2 years...