# What is the best process to install a node based service/daemon/unit on Debian 11?

Tags: systemd, node.js, systemctl

In this post:
[Other serverfault post][1]
[1]: https://serverfault.com/questions/1018676/how-to-configure-systemd-service-unit-to-start-node-app-with-npm-start-instead

I found that it's possible to add a node based service to the system without having to create an apt package. It would be nice if systemctl and journalctl -u worked with the new service.

I found this guide helpful:
[Blog post][2]
[2]: https://nodesource.com/blog/running-your-node-js-app-with-systemd-part-1/

In looking at how other services are implemented, it appears there are a few steps:

1. Install/create your node service file/s in a folder on the system
2. Create a file /lib/systemd/system/.service. Add the
   provper Environment lines, etc.
3. sudo systemctl daemon-reload
4. systemctl enable token-server (also creates the symlink to
   /etc/systemd/system/.service)